# Can I use greenrobot EventBus for Communication between Activity and Service?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service, greenrobot-eventbus

[EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) Can I use this library for Activity to Service communication ?

I have tried this in my app as follows:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_music_player);
    Intent serviceIntent=new Intent(MusicPlayerActivityTest.this,MusicPlayerServiceTest.class);
    startService(serviceIntent);
    EventBus.getDefault().post(new SetSongList(songArraList, 0));
}
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

and in my service `onEvent` called

Comment: did you try it before posting here?

Comment: yes i tried. but am getting an error says "Subscriber class has no public methods called onEvent"

Comment: well... that's a different thing. You should post some code and logcat so we can help you to fix it (if possible)

Comment: can u explain how to use it?

Comment: "am getting an error says "Subscriber class has no public methods called onEvent"" -- we cannot help you with your subscriber, unless you post the code for your subscriber. In general, yes, you can use greenrobot's `EventBus` to communicate from a service to an activity (or vice versa). See https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/EventBus/GreenRobot for an example.

Comment: But onEvent is not calling on service

Comment: @MarianoZorrilla what makes you think that he didnt try?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You have to register the Subscriber, not the emitter.

So, remove register/unregister from your app if you do expect to get the event. If so, just add the `onEvent` (AnyEvent event) method to the Application class.

Then register EventBus in your service in `onStart()` and unregister in `onStop()`.

It should work better then.

**In your Application**

```
public class MyApp extend Application {
  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    ...
    EventBus.getDefault().post(new SetSongList(songArraList, 0));
  }
}
```

**or in your Activity**

```
public class MyActivity extend Activity {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    EventBus.getDefault().post(new SetSongList(songArraList, 0));
  }
}
```

**and in your Service**

```
public class MyService extends Service {
  ...
  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
  }

  @Override
  public void onDestroy() {
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
    super.onDestroy();
  }

  public void onEvent(SetSongList event){
    // do something with event
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `@Subscribe public void onEvent(SetSongList event){`?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anyway, it produces the following error:
 
 
Could not dispatch event: class someEvent to subscribing class class someService
                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create    handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Comment: This is for EventBus 2.4, the API changed with the new version 3.0. Post your code in a new thread that I can have a look.

Comment: what if i want to make the communication vice-versa? from the service to the activiity ? how can i do that?

Comment: Activity -> Service event flow will only work if the service runs in the same process.

Answer (score 5):

In my case comment by *zyamys* helped. Also, answer by *Anthony* is correct because of mistake in code.

In case you use a different **process**, the answer is **NO**. If you use different process it means it runs on a different virtual machine (like Davlik). All static fields are different...! 
Example (AndroidManifest.xml):

```
<service android:name=".GPSTracker" android:process=":my_gps_tracker" />
```

If you run service in the same process answer is **YES**. Example (AndroidManifest.xml):

```
<service android:name=".GPSTracker"/>
```

In the first case, I suggest of using Intents in combination with send/receive broadcast functionality to send data between service and activity.